# Print image on existing baked texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking

I'm using Blender 2.79, which for several reasons, is the one that suits my needs. So, I had a 3d model that I imported that had many materials. I needed that model for a game, so I made a smart UV unwrap for getting my UV map, and then, baked my texture, deleted the materials and applied the baked texture. The model I'm currently using, is quite complex, so the output baked texture has some deffects that I would like to correct by hand. My plan is to "print" a logo on a bad-quality area, but still don't figure out how.

This is my baked texture:

[image: This is my baked texture:]

This is the texture applied to the model. There should be the republic sigil. Instead, there is that weird pokemon.

[image: This is the texture applied to the model. There should be the republic sigil. Instead, there is that weird pokemon.]
I'd like to "print" the following in there:

Is there a way to do so?

[image]

Also, in a similar manner, I'd like to put this image in the side spheres. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Create a new UV map just for the disks. Combine your material so that it maps your image texture using the new UV map.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. I didn't think about that. Thank you!